# handling LTR and RTL for Arabic Sites (internationalization) Magento

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I am creating a site in magento,It is basically an english site but when user clicks on translate it translate it into Arabic.There is problem of ltr and rtl,How can I solve that.I am using GTRANSLATE EXTENSION right now.Same is the case with urdu ,kurdish languages. Anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0):

Rtl also be implemented through css in below given way:
* {
    direction:rtl;
}

Comment: You just need to use any class that contains all body. And then write below code in css file.
.class{
direction:rtl;
}

Answer (score 0):

If your theme doesn't support RTL, then:
1. you'll need to locate your CSS files in your theme and copy them to a new child theme (search in google for "magento child theme creation")
2. convert the copied css files to RTL by using online tools such as http://rtlcss.com
3. create or edit a view in your magento store (example arabic view) and select the that view in your configuration--> add the child theme in Design (make sure you selected the right view).